# Accessing a Drive Preview from an iFrame in Chrome via SSL

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application that uses Google Drive for document storage and preview functionality, but recently the iFrames that the documents are loading into are not displaying anything. Upon inspection of the console, Chrome declares that it blocked the fram from running insecure content, and that is why the file preview did not load.

The initial call to preview this file is to a url that looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d//preview

There is a redirect along the way that takes the following form but because it uses http instead of https, Chrome blocks the content from loading.

http://www.google.com/url?sa=p&q=https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service%3Dwise%26passive%3Dtrue%26go%3Dtrue%26continue%3Dhttps://docs.google.com/document/d//preview?pref%253D2%2526pli%253D1

Is there any way around this issue? It is blocking a core functionality of my application currently, so any advice would be appreciated. I can provide a screenshot of the full stack of network loads in necessary, but this is the only URL that is not http compliant.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just ran into same stuff. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Hi @igorpavlov - I ended up setting the convert tag to be true on the code, and then used the embedLink returned by the upload in the iFrame. It stopped giving us SSL errors and is working correctly now.

Comment: Hey! As I know embedLink shows view mode only. For /edit mode use my solution. If you need of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Hacked that. Add a "?pli=1" without quotes at the end of the URL to avoid redirect (after "/preview" or "/edit") and land directly to the document.